# Using IRMI (From VIM package) to impute missing values

Tags: r

Has anyone used IRMI(VIM) to impute missing Age? Playing around with titanic data and multiple imputation packages. When invoking IRMI, I hoped that the missing values would be filled, but it doesnt seem to have done anything. Is my implementation incorrect? Age is a numeric variable...

My code is below. Any insight into why this won't work will be very helpful...

Thanks,
simak

```
   trainData<-read.csv("titanic.csv",header=TRUE)
   > summary(trainData$Age)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   0.42   20.12   28.00   29.70   38.00   80.00     177 

   library(VIM)
   > library(VIM)
   > countNA(trainData)
   [1] 177

   > imputed.train <- irmi(trainData,mixed=NULL)
   Time difference of -0.08631301 secs
   Imputation performed on the following data set:
                type      #missing
   PassengerId "integer" "0"     
   Survived    "binary"  "0"     
   Pclass      "integer" "0"     
   Name        "nominal" "0"     
   Sex         "binary"  "0"     
   Age         "numeric" "177"   
   SibSp       "integer" "0"     
   Parch       "integer" "0"     
   Ticket      "nominal" "0"     
   Fare        "numeric" "0"     
   Cabin       "nominal" "0"     
   Embarked    "nominal" "0"     
   IsChild     "numeric" "0"     

   > countNA(imputed.train)
   [1] 177

   I understand that in this case, using a measure of central tendency will suffice to filling in the missing values, but would like to know why this didnt work. 

   The dataframe has mixed data types and Age is numeric.
```

Thanks,
simak